# Nginx mutliple rewrite rules per location

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, rewrite

I've got a working nginx rewrite for a location, but in the case of a specific request I want to rewrite to a different location.

```
location /api {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite "^/api/.{2}\.zip" /api/general.zip last; break;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/router.php?rest_data=$1 last; break;
     }
}
```

So if someone requests */api/uk.zip* then it downloads fine, but */api/fr.zip* doesn't exist, so it should redirect to */api/general.zip*

I've tried 2 location blocks, I get a duplicate location error, and I've tried using 2 if statements, but the second one gets ignored.

If the request is for something else, like */api/events* then it should forward to the router page.

Comment: Ok I fixed it, that works fine except I need to wrap the first regex in double quotes, due to the curly braces `{}` in the expression. Pointed out to me from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684463/curly-braces-and-from-apache-to-nginx-rewrite-rules

Comment: Scrap that, there was a syntax error which is now fixed but I still can't get 2 rewrite rules to work, it just listens to the first rule

Comment: Is it valid to use both last; break; at the end of a rewrite directive?

Comment: I'm new to nginx, I took over from someone elses config, it seems to work so I can't really comment beyond that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If-Is-Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), avoid using if. You're a starter on nginx and maybe you didn't saw that before (check [this guide](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/02/nginx-primer-2-from-apache-to-nginx/) for a good start). But really, avoid if. And the solution is usually [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) instead.

In your case a unique `try_file` cannot be used, because you need to apply a special treatment if the zip file is a two character one. But with two locations it should work.
Something like that (untested):

```
location ^~ "/api/([0-9a-zA-Z]{2}).zip"  {
    try_files $uri /api/general.zip;
}
location ^~ "/api/(.*)" {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/router.php?rest_data=$1;
}
```

Comment: That looks about right, I ended up doing something similar, but is your answer missing a closing bracket?